# What determines the harmony in colors

Tags: user-interface, colors

I am learning to build my app from A to Z, I have to do some UI design (to which I am totally an igorant). I have a question, please spare your valuable time to answer it.

The colors in the following picture look in harmony,it seems to me all the colors are somewhat milky. What is the term / technical word / jargon for that quality.

If I have some colors, say: brown, yellow, red, blue, green, how can I make them in harmony like this? Is there any basic tips for color combination?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Milkiness' is probably that they are 'pastel colours' .  In terms of colour-harmonies there are a few good tools out there for picking colour schemes.  http://www.sessions.edu/color-calculator seems to be particularly straightforward.  If you want pastel colours, pick colours toward the centre of the colour-wheel.

Comment: Thank you for your link, it's valuable to me!

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to describe relationships between various colors. Typically we refer to colors in terms of their relationship on the **Color Wheel.** If an object appears to have around the same shades/hues of colors and is pleasing to the eye, it is said to have a **balanced color scheme** 
In your case, I would consider this scheme for the overall theme, triadic or tetradic.
[image]
[image]

Pictures courtesy of: [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/learn-the-basics-of-color-theory-to-know-what-looks-goo-1608972072)